# Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector (char positions)

Tags: c

I already read some posts about this, but I still can't fix my code.

```
int numericValue(char s, int i) {
    if (strcmp(s[i], "$") == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return value(s[i]) + numericValue(s, i + 1);
}
```

This is my code, and if I change `int numericValue(char s, int i)` for `int numericValue(char *s, int i)` I have this warning:

> passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion].

What could I do?

Comment: `cad` is not an array so you can't use array notation. You want to pas a `char *` to `valorNumerico`

Comment: Please add the line of code where you call `valorNumerico` (initially)

Comment: ...followed by `if(cad[i] == '$')` and remove all the unnecessary `comparacion ` stuff.

Comment: Note that `strcmp()` requires a `char *` for its first argument.  Even if you change the function signature to include `char *cad`, the `strcmp()` isn't going to compile.  You need to think rather carefully what you're up to.  It might be that you need `comparacion = (cad[i] != '$');` but it isn't clear what you're after so the answer can't be clear either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to compare two characters use double equals sign(==) as below and mind those single quotes around dollar sign as character literals are enclosed in single quotes,

```
int numericValue(char* s, int i) {
if (s[i] == '$')
    return 0;
else
    return value(s[i]) + numericValue(s, i + 1);
}
```

One will use strcmp to compare two strings, but in your case you are passing a character to strcmp as first argument which is a mismatch. See strcmp signature below:

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```